# a significance test to see if there is a relationship between smokers and urinary incontinance

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

a recent experiment investigated the relationship between smoking and urinary incontinence. of the 150 subjects in the study who were incontinent, 100 were smokers. of the 150 control subjects who were not incontinent, 70 were smokers. please try to do a significance test to see if there is a relationship between smoking and incontinence.

so what i tried to work out is,

1. set the hypothesis as h0:pi1=pi2 h1: pi1=/pi2   alpha=0.05
   but i am completely stuck on how to find the df? is it 149? or am i using the wrong formula?
   since i am completely lost on the df, i am even more lost on which formula to use to find sd and furthermore the T. it feels like i am lacking so much data to even go forth with the calculation. help?

p.s. i got t=0.44 but i dont even remember how i got it, and my conclusion was there is a statistical significance.

Comment: Are you sure a t-test is the way to go here? Have you covered chi-squared in your course yet?

Comment: A t statistic 0.44, if appropriate, would not be significant. My answer tries to point you in a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a test to determine if two binomial success probabilities are equal. In R, this the procedure `prop.test` does the test as shown below. The very small P-value indicates there is a statistical difference between the two groups.

```
prop.test(c(100,70), c(150, 150))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions
        with continuity correction

data:  c(100, 70) out of c(150, 150)
X-squared = 11.416, df = 1, p-value = 0.000728
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.08349242 0.31650758
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.6666667 0.4666667
```

For details of such a test see [this page](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm).